# How can I accurately select an area of screen to record when using RecordMyDesktop?

Tags: screencast, recordmydesktop

When using RecordMyDesktop I want to select an area of the screen to record, not just a particular window or the whole screen. The application instructs you to click and drag to select the area you want to record in the preview window, however this preview is very small and I can't find any way to make it larger (maximizing the window makes no difference)

[image]

Is there a way to make the preview window larger so that I can make a more accurate selection of the area I want to record. I'd prefer to use RecordMyDesktop rather than another screencaster as its the only one that seems to work faultlessly for me.

Comment: Have tried setting the offset, width, and hight of the window?

Comment: @Mitch Yep, changing the size of the window doesn't make it any bigger. http://i.stack.imgur.com/iya3N.png

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can click your actual desktop instead of the small preview and select an area to record.

To do that open *recordmydesktop* and right click on the application indicator on the top right corner of the screen and click on ***Select Area On Screen***

[image]

it will create an overlay of the current screen where you can select an area to record.

Just left click anywhere and drag the mouse to select the area and you are done. Happy recordings (:

[image]

Comment: But it doesn't work for a secondary monitor. :(

Comment: recordMyDesktop's interface could really use some love. But I'm lazy.